# Aframe/threejs: calculate a point "behind" another element

Tags: vector, three.js, 3d, aframe

Lets say we have two elements, A and B, both with known positions; I need get the position of a point that is facing the direction between A and B, and X meters distant from B.

I guess I need to create a "line" from A to B, extend it of another X meters, and get the point at the end of the line.

How to translate this in vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like so:

```
const x = 2;
const a = new THREE.Vector3();
const b = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
const v = new THREE.Vector3(); // the result vector

v.subVectors( a, b );
v.normalize();
v.multiplyScalar( x );
v.add( b ); // v is now (0, 0, - 1)
```

Full working example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/15820/